# Custom command not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, shell

In my Ubuntu I tried to create a custom command:

1. I added a bash script named `ns3` in `/usr/bin`

   ```
    #!/bin/bash  
    cd ns3/ns3-allinone-3.19/ns-3.19
   ```
2. I made it executable

   ```
   chmod +x ns3
   ```

Still it doesn't work, when I try the same command manually it works.
Why ? Is it that I can't do it this way?

Comment: Because when you execute your command and the bash script ends you fall back in the former directory. You have to do a function and source it to make persistent the directory change.

Comment: @Hastur could you give som example on how to do that. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It should be said here that you shouldn't be placing custom commands in /usr/bin, that's what /usr/local/bin is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute your script it runs in a different shell. 
There you change the local directory but when it is finished you fall back in the original directory.

You can both do an alias or a function (if you need to pass some parameter).

```
 alias ns3='cd ns3/ns3-allinone-3.19/ns-3.19'
```

it should work for you. Put in your `~/.bash_aliases` if you have one. It's an hidden files (it starts with `.` and it is in your home directory `~`). If not you can add a `source ~/.alias` as last line of your `.bashrc` and write all your aliases in that file. When you will work with another machine you can always copy the `.alias` and add a single line to your new `.bashrc`.

---

A function

```
  Hello() { echo "Hello " $1 " here I am for you" ; }
```

From the prompt you write `Hello Adriano` and the shell will answer `Hello Adriano here I am for you`. `$1` for the 1st parameter `$2` for the second...